# Why can't I access my ArcGIS Server externally?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, configuration, arcgis-web-adaptor

> I have Windows 2012 Server x64 with SQL Server 2012.
>
> I'm also using IIS 8 as a web server on the same machine.
>
> I've installed ArcGIS for Server 10.1 SP1 and ArcSDE 10.1 both on the
> same server.
>
> I've also installed the Web Adapter 10.1 SP1.

I configured the Web Adapter's GIS Server URL to MyServer:6080

The Web Adapter returned:

> Status: The following GIS servers are registered to your Web Adaptor
>
> MyServer

The firewall on the server is currently off.

Port 80 on the router has been forwarded.

I want to be able to access the rest services off network via

External IP/arcgis/rest/services

Do I need to set certain settings in IIS for the Web Adapater?

Comment: What do you see in ArcGIS Server Manager when you go to Site>Web Adaptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your Web-Adaptor may be resolving only to your machines local DNS name, in your example case 'MyServer' versus what name/ip you would potentially connect to it as from another machine. 
So in this case you need to make sure both your points can resolve to name/ip so that you can get to them via the URL-ReWriting that the Web-Adaptor does to access to back end port.

Comment: Can I simply go to /arcgis/webadaptor and reconfigure the web adaptor from there? Or do I need to uninstall it and reinstall?

Comment: I haven't been back to 10.1 enough to be sure. Try going through from the external connection and ping through to that IP address and make sure you are getting to it, and then try hitting just the default web-page for IIS to make sure you are seeing port 80.

Comment: You can reconfigure your web adapter with the external ip or registered domain for the same. Go through start button web adapter

Comment: What do you mean by start button web adaptor?

Comment: Ok, that means in your router/firewall you are not configured to pass through to your server. You probably need to configure NAT as well as set up the rules that a request for port 80 goes to that IP you assigned to your server.